# Codeigniter - Regular expression in if statement?

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, uri

I would like to know how to implement a regular expression into the following statement:

```
if($this->uri->segment(3) !== 'a,b,c...') {
         redirect 'tools/glossary';
        }
```

I need to check that the uri segment is only one character in length and only alphabetical.

If not then redirect to the glossary page.

How is this possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have answered, preg_match will work for you.  However, Just to throw in an alternative, codeigniter accepts regex in the routing rules, so you could have something in your `config/routes.php` like

```
$route['somecontroller/someaction/([a-zA-Z])'] = "somecontroller/someaction/$1";
$route['somecontroller/someaction/(:any)'] = "tools/glossary";
```

To avoid a redirect

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z]$/i', $this->uri->segment(3))) {
    redirect('tools/glossary');
}
```

Comment: Just to point out what the regex says: ^ means beginning of the string, $ means end of the string, and i means that the match is case insensitive.

Comment: Also, uh... shouldn't that be "if (!preg_match"? OP wants to redirect is the segment does *not* match.